# output of c code

Tags: c, header, stdio, sqrt

Why output is giving 3 , expecting -3.  How to handle such preprocessing in c?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#define sq(x) ((x<0)?sqrt(-x):sqrt(x))

int main()
{
    int x;
    x=sq(-9);
    printf("%d\n",x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you expecting the output to be `-3`?

Comment: Why would you expect the result of any square root to be a negative number???

Comment: ALWAYS put macro arguments in their own parentheses! As in `#define sq(x) (((x)<0)?sqrt(-(x)):sqrt(x))`. Imagine if you had `sq(a+b)` in an expression ... `-(a+b)` is not the same as `-a+b`.

Comment: Presumably you really intended something like `(((x)<0)?-sqrt(-(x)):...`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

because your # define "sq"  checks if its a negative number and turns it into a positive number before calculating a square root

its doing sqrt(-x)   which is sqrt(-(-9))    ( taking the negative of a negative is the positive)

so its doing sqrt(9)

Comment: if we write sqrt(--9) directly than it give error...and in c (--9) doesnt have any mean...so how can u tell here sqrt(--9) ( taking the negative of a negative is the positive)

Comment: @anil write `sqrt(-(-9))` c thought you meant to use the decrement operator.

Comment: @anil: He did not say `--9`. He said `-(-9)`.

Answer (score 1):

You have this define:

```
define sq(x)  ((x<0)?sqrt(-x):sqrt(x))
```

Since you're passing -9, `x<0` is true, so it's doing `sqrt(9)`, which is 3.

You then print the 3.

Answer (score 1):

The code is doing exactly what it's being told, I think.

`sq(x)` tests first for `x < 0` - in your case, this is true, so `sq(x)` calls `sqrt(-(-9))` - which is 3.

An attempted solution is `(x < 0) ? -sqrt(-x) : sqrt(x)`, which will return negative roots for negative `x` (my best interpretation of your intent).

Comment: but actually preprocessor just replace x with passed value..so sq(-9) should be seem like this ((-9<0)?sqrt(--9):sqrt(9))...and it should be give an error...but u tell it replace like this sqrt(-(-9))...how it is possible

Comment: I believe `-1 * x` will work. (`--9` being `-1 * -9` being passed into `sqrt`)

Answer (score 1):

Wait, wait, wait.

Are we trying to break the basic rules of Math here?

The square root of -9 is 3 **i**.

That's because (-3)^2 is 9. Negative numbers have 'imaginary' square roots. sqrt(-1) is **i**. Not -1. (-1)^2 is 1.

Answer (score 0):

If you expect `-3`, then you probably meant

```
#define sq(x)  ((x<0)?-sqrt(-x):sqrt(x))
```

but why would you expect negative square root of negative number is beyond me.

Comment: He probably does not want to do `sqrt(-9)`...  maybe `-sqrt(-x)`?

Comment: So, basically, due to absurdity of expectation, it might have been `#define sq(x) -3` :-)